# Yii Framework - getting current value of input field

Tags: php, yii

I have a YiiStrap textfield and I want to send the value to the controller of this View. Currently I am hard coding the value but I want to get the current value of the input field. Does anyone know how to do this? The onclick should call the function on the controller and pass the textfield's current value with it. Below is my code:

```
    <?php echo TbHtml::textField('text', '', array('id' => 'inputSearch', 'value' => 'hello', 'append' => 
TbHtml::button('test', '', array(
     'class' => 'lookup',
     'id' => 'lookup',
      'color' => TbHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_PRIMARY,
       //'onclick' => TbHtml::listData(HighSchoolDistrict::model()->findAll(), 'High_School_District_Name', 'High_School_District_Name'),
      'onclick' => $this->actionDoSomething('bal'),
    )

 ))); ?>
```

Comment: onClick parameter calls a javascript function, if you want to get the current value on the input while is being typed, then you should look for Ajax..

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to post value in controller:

```
$("#lookup").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('site/search');?>",
        data: {inputSeach: $("#inputSearch").val()},
        success:function(){}
    });
});
```

Comment: So would I put this on my view? in a script tag?

Comment: This is working but I cant access the data on the my controller, I am using $_POST['data']

Comment: Yes, you put this on your view. In your controller, you use $_POST["inputSearch"]